# Django deployment with gunicorn socket set up with systemd, gunicorn not honoring gunicorn.conf file settings on Debian 9.4

Tags: debian, django, systemd, socket, gunicorn

I followed the systemd deployment instructions here at http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/deploy.html

/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn3.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn3 daemon
Requires=gunicorn3.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
PIDFile=/run/gunicorn3/pid
User=feritsuser
Group=feritsuser
RuntimeDirectory=gunicorn3
WorkingDirectory=/home/feritsuser/Ferits
ExecStart=/usr/bin/gunicorn3 --pid /run/gunicorn3/pid   \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn3/socket Ferits.wsgi
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
ExecStop=/bin/kill -s TERM $MAINPID
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn3.socket

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn3 socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn3/socket

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

/etc/tmpfiles.d/gunicorn3.conf:

```
d /run/gunicorn3 0755 feritsuser feritsuser \
--workers 2 \
--timeout 300 \
--error-logfile /var/log/gunicorn3/error.log \
--log-level=debug
```

I have gunicorn.conf symlinked to gunicorn3.conf as well.

My nginx proxy to the gunicorn socket is working. I can load the application and use it in a browser, but I'm getting a 502 timeout on one page. Nginx error log is:

> 2018/07/25 10:31:18 [error] 614#614: *3 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 10.18.3.145, server: _, request: "GET /browse/expenses/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/run/gunicorn3/socket:/browse/expenses/", host: "10.18.3.59", referrer: "http://10.18.3.59/"

The timeout is occurring after 30 seconds, and it's not writing to the log file specified in gunicorn3.conf/gunicorn.conf, so it appears that my socket implementation is not honoring the .conf file. What am I doing wrong? I've tried chowning the .conf files for feritsuser:feritsuser, and still, nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I was never able to get it to use the .conf file, even when specifying it in gunicorn3.service. What ended up working was just getting rid of the .conf file completely and changing my gunicorn3.service file like so:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn3 daemon
Requires=gunicorn3.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
PIDFile=/run/gunicorn3/pid
User=feritsuser
Group=feritsuser
RuntimeDirectory=gunicorn3
WorkingDirectory=/home/feritsuser/Ferits
ExecStart=/usr/bin/gunicorn3 --pid /run/gunicorn3/pid \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn3/socket Ferits.wsgi \
          --workers 2 \
          --timeout 300 \
          --error-logfile /var/log/gunicorn3/error.log \
          --log-level=debug
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
ExecStop=/bin/kill -s TERM $MAINPID
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```